# Pyqt5 QTableWidget selectionChanged missing required argument 'slot' (pos 1)

Tags: pyqt5, qt-signals

I tried to connect to a method of QTableWidget object with QtCore.pyqtSignal() object, but this method expects me to return a value. Frankly, I couldn't find where I went wrong.

Table class

```
class TABLE(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    current = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TABLE, self).__init__(parent)
        self.show()

    def selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        self.current.emit()
```

App class

```
from x import TABLE
class WpApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WpApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        data = [["1","Hello, How are you","12-09-2022"]]
        self.task = TABLE(data, self)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.tablo)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def tablo(self):
        self.task.current.connect()
```

I got this error when run it: **TypeError: connect() missing required argument 'slot' (pos 1)**

Why does the selectionChanged method expect me to return a value?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `selectionChanged`. The `connect` function of a signal expects a slot/function as argument (as you did for `clicked`), but you didn't provide any, which doesn't make sense since the whole point of signals is to *connect to something*. Also remove the `connectSlotsByName` line, which is useless for your code.

Comment: i figured out what i did wrong so how do i get the values returned by the selectionChanged method in the 'tablo' method ''for example self.sender().current_col ?''

Comment: Add arguments to the signal declaration and emit them using what you need. See [the documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).